# Regex to find lines that match a specific pattern

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a txt file and it has the data has a `///////////`  to divide the results. I need to find the results that only have 1 line.

I've tried but I can't seem to figure out how to differentiate the multiple lines between the `///////////`

For example, I just need to find the a and the d.

```
/////////// 
a
///////////
b
c
//////////
d
/////////
```

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will pull the letters you need into a capturing group:

```
\/+\s+(\S+)\s+(?=\/+)
```

Explanation:

- At least one `/`, followed by
- At least one whitespace `\s` (includes newlines), followed by
- At least one non-whitespace character `\S`, followed by
- At least one whitespace `\s`, and
- At least one `/`, in a positive lookahead group

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/pHg9ov/3

Comment: It will not work in [this case](https://regex101.com/r/pHg9ov/2)

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `^/+\R\K.+(?=\R/+$)`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Find All in Current Document</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
  /+        # 1 or more slashes
  \R        # any kind of linebreak
\K          # reset match
.+          # 1 or more any character but newline
(?=         # positive look ahead, make sure we have after:
  \R          # any kind of linebreak
  /+          # 1 or more slashes
  $           # end of ine
)           # end look ahead
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]